# Simple component to crop a picture with rectangle box in c#.net windows application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, crop

I want a simple component to crop a picture with Rectangle box in c#.net windows application.what component can i use?(free or purchase)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here's](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/graph/programmatically-resizing-an-image) some code I wrote to resize an image. The code will also trim the image if needed.

It provides an example of cropping and could easily be modified to be a more general "cropper" class.

Answer (score 2):

I used [ClearImage](http://www.inliteresearch.com/image-processing/) for image manipulation at a previous job. I found it very easy to use, with good performance and it would serve your purpose perfectly.

There is also [AForge](http://code.google.com/p/aforge/), a open source image manipulation library. A little more powerfull, with a lot of features, but also a little more complicated.

Or you could design your own using the PictureBox and the Bitmap class. A lot of work, and probably not very performant if you don't know what you're doing...